# Partition integer into n parts, with constraint on each part

Tags: combinatorics

$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are integer numbers in the range [0,B-1]. Count the number of solution for
$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=k$.

I know this problem is similar to the one here
[Number of ways of partitioning a sum into ordered non-negative summands](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42210/number-of-ways-of-partitioning-a-sum-into-ordered-non-negative-summands)

But now there is constraint on the range of $x_i$. In the problem text it gives a hint to use principle of inclusion and exclusion. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see how the first question you linked is related, but the second is essentially the same, so I'll vote to close.

Comment: @tomasz: They’re all three essentially the same question: how many solutions in non-negative integers are there to $\sum_{k=1}^mx_k=n$ subject to the constraint that each $x_k\le b$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see now. You're right. :)